# Java BigDecimal remove decimal and trailing numbers

Tags: java, decimal, bigdecimal

I'm new to Java and trying to take a BigDecimal (for example 99999999.99) and convert it to a string but without the decimal place and trailing numbers. Also, I don't want commas in the number and rounding is not needed.

I've tried:

```
Math.Truncate(number)
```

but BigDecimal is not supported.

Any ideas?

Thanks very much.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Try `number.toBigInteger().toString()`

Comment: u changed the data type

Answer (score 66):

Use this.

```
BigDecimal truncated= number.setScale(0,BigDecimal.ROUND_DOWN);
```

Comment: This is the most appropriate answer as it does not change the data type

Comment: For me, this still leaves the decimal place and trailing numbers

Answer (score 9):

BigDecimal without fractions is BigInteger. Why don't you just use BigInteger?

Answer (score 5):

Here's the most elegant way I found to resolve this:

```
public static String convertDecimalToString (BigDecimal num){
    String ret = null;
    try {
        ret = num.toBigIntegerExact().toString();
    } catch (ArithmeticException e){
        num = num.setScale(2,BigDecimal.ROUND_UP); 
        ret = num.toPlainString();
    }
    return ret;
}
```

Comment: `num = num.setScale(2,BigDecimal.ROUND_UP);`
You mean : `num = num.setScale(0,BigDecimal.ROUND_UP);`

Answer (score 0):

```
private void showDoubleNo(double n) {
    double num = n; 
    int decimalPlace = 2; 
    BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal(num); 
    bd = bd.setScale(decimalPlace,BigDecimal.ROUND_UP); 
    System.out.println("Point is "+bd); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static String convertBigDecimalToString(BigDecimal bg) {
      System.out.println("Big Decimal Value before its convertion :" + bg.setScale(2, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP));

      String bigDecStringValue = bg.setScale(0,BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP).toPlainString();

      System.out.println("Big Decimal String Value after removing Decimal places is :" + bigDecStringValue);

      return bigDecStringValue;
}
```

Please note : I have used 'BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP' , just to make sure, Rounding mode to round towards "nearest neighbor" unless both neighbors are equidistant

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
number.toPlainString();
```